# Make app exit in OnBackButtonPressed method for xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have an application in which user logins. Now I want that user can't go back to the menu after he presses the logout button.

This is my logout method

```
public async void OnLogoutButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App.AuthenticationClient.UserTokenCache.Clear(Constants.ApplicationID);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
        }
```

So after logout button is clicked it pushes the user to login page.
I'm able to disable the back button using this in login page

```
 protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
   {

      return false;
   }
```

But it makes my app feel not responsive, instead, I want that when the back button is pressed my app should close the application. 
I tried this

```
     protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
       {

          return exit();
          //
          // exit()
       }
```

but it returns boolean, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user logs out, you generally don't want to push a new page on the existing navigation stack.  The current navigation stack is not longer applicable, so should be discarded, much like how you clear the UserTokenCache.

So your logout method should be more like:

```
public async void OnLogoutButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.AuthenticationClient.UserTokenCache.Clear(Constants.ApplicationID);
    Application.Current.MainPage = new LoginPage();
}
```

Basically, create the new LoginPage and set up a new MainPage, just as though the app were starting and first presenting the user with a LoginPage.

If you do that, then the back button can't get back to the menu, because that whole navigation stack is gone.